# How to decode in PHP RSA OAEP encoded in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, rsa

So, I have some encryption/decryption issues …

I encrypt data in javascript thanks to node-forge and I try to decrypt it into PHP thanks to openssl_private_decrypt.

On the PHP side, I use the «OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING» padding. So, on the javascript side I tried to configure forge to encrypt data with RSA-OAEP.

And when I try to decsypt the message on the PHP side, I have these errors :

> error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error
>    error:04065072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed

I've tried to configure the encryption with sha1 message digest and sha1 for mgf1 option.   I've also tried without any option (if I remember, forge use SHA256 by default).  But there is nothing to do, I always have the same error …

javascript

```
const pubkey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
`;
const privkey = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
`;
let publicKey = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(pubkey);
let key = forge.random.getBytesSync(32);
let encKey = publicKey.encrypt(key, 'RSA-OAEP', {
        md: forge.md.sha1.create(),
        mgf1: {
          md: forge.md.sha1.create()
        }
      });
let b64Key = encodeURIComponent(btoa(enckey));
```

Next, I send the key in url with the "xcem" param, thanks to HttpClient. And I receive it in PHP.

php

```
$privKey = "";
$b64Key = urldecode($_GET['xcem']);
$encKey = base64_decode($b64Key);
$key = null;
if (!openssl_private_decrypt($encKey, $key, file_get_contents('/keys/openssl_private.key'), OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) 
{
    $errorssl = [];
    while ($error = openssl_error_string()) {
        $errorssl[] = $error;
    }
    throw new Exception("Erreur lors du décryptage du message ! " . json_encode($errorssl));
}
```

When I send Data between 2 PHP servers, there is no problem …
But I can't make it work between JS and PHP … I need some help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo …
After some tests, and headaches I found the problem … In my original code (not the one here) I sent the key, the init vector, the signature and the encrypted data …
But in my PHP, I tried to decode the signature … I didn't send data in the right order …
My bad …